# Conflict/overlap between header fancyhdr and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr, overlap

The second page of the table of contents is conflicting with the header of the page.

[image: Example of conflict on the second page of ToC]

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper, xcolor=table]{report}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%header
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{logo.png}}
    \fancyhead[R]{My title}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\begin{document}
    
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}}

\newpage

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{0}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

~
\thispagestyle{plain}
%recommencer la numérotation des pages à "1"
\setcounter{page}{0}

\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\section{two}
\section{three}

\end{document}
```

I've tried to change the geometry settings but the header and the ToC are moving together so the issue persists. I also tried changing the title spacing, but I can't see any difference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You need to reserve space for your logo and page headers, For example by adding `headheight=2cm, headsep=1ex` to `geometry` options.

Comment: Try  `\usepackage[head=120pt,top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm,includehead]{geometry}`

Comment: @Zarko I tried your settings, it's almost working, but the header ends up too high or is cut by the top of the page. It's probably the right directions, but I tried playing with this settings before posting and cannot have a consistent results

Comment: @Biorix, consult `geometry` package documentation for all possible settings. The sizes of parameters you need to determine yourself  (we haven't your logo image)

Comment: @Zarko Yes, I've read the doc and it really confuses me. I figured out a solution, but I'm not sure to post it as I'm uncertain as if it's a proper way. I put what you said but by adding ```\setlength{\topmargin}{-2cm}``` it somehow corrected the "too high" problem